# Stopping times of Lévy-type processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

I'm trying to find conditions on the symbol $q(x,\xi)$ of a Lévy-type process $X$ (d-dimensional) such that the following stopping time $\tau_u^{\alpha}$ is a.s. finite;
$$ \tau^\alpha _u=\inf\left\{t\geq 0:\alpha^TX\geq u\right\},$$
where $\alpha$ is some element in $\mathbb{R}^d_{\geq 0}$ (better would be $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}^d$) and $u\in\mathbb{R}$.

With the long time behaviour result in [Bötcher, Schilling, Wang (2010) *Lévy matters III*] Theorem 5. 18, I have the answer for processes on a positive domain and for symmetric processes. But how do I approach this Problem in general?

Any hints to existing literature etc. are welcome.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Would you please shoot me an email? My address is in my profile.